# Who is "Sid Viscosity"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, alternative-rock

The lyrics of the song *[Gentle Spike Resort](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHlq42K0jeY)* by [Grandaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandaddy) refer to Sid Viscosity:

> With ex-school treasures for hire
>   And whitesnake riffs dressed up like Sid Viscosity

"Whitesnake" *could* refer to [Deep Purple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Purple)'s [David Coverdale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Coverdale)'s band [Whitesnake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitesnake), in which case I assume the sound of 'Sid Viscosity' is close to but idiosyncratic enough to differentiate it from Whitesnake's, but "Sid Viscosity" doesn't give me any reasonable hits inside or outside that musical context.

Who - or what - is Sid Viscosity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sid Viscosity is probably a reference to [Sid Vicious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sid_Vicious) (1957-1979), one of the members of the punk rock band the "Sex Pistols". The references to punk continue in the lyrics:

> You're not the only one who's doing without
>   Daddy doctor's son punk rocker shouts
>   "Dad the A.C.'s broke in our hardcore punk rock vacation
>   Vacation rehearsal house"